# Create a list of indexed variables and assign values in one line of code

Tags: list-manipulation, variable-definitions

It is easy to create a list of indexed variables

```
F/@{1,3,6,8}
```

I would like to assign values in the same line of code

```
F/@{1,3,6,8}={2,4,6,0}
```

but it complains Set::write: Tag Map in F/@{1,3,6,8} is Protected.
Why, whats going on?

Answer (score 8):

```
Evaluate[F /@ {1, 3, 6, 8}] = {2, 4, 6, 0}
```

Comment: @PhillipDukes - As shown, since `Set` has the attribute `HoldFirst`, you must `Evaluate` the LHS

Answer (score 8):

another method:

```sh
F = AssociationThread[{1, 3, 6, 8} -> {2, 4, 6, 0}]
F[1]
```

> 2

Answer (score 3):

Just another way:

```
Clear@F;
Set @@ {F /@ {1, 3, 6, 8}, {2, 4, 6, 0}};

DownValues@F
(*{HoldPattern[F[1]] :> 2, HoldPattern[F[3]] :> 4, HoldPattern[F[6]] :> 6, HoldPattern[F[8]] :> 0}*)

F /@ {1, 3, 6, 8}
(*{2, 4, 6, 0}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear[F]
MapThread[Set,{F /@ {1, 3, 6, 8}, {2, 4, 6, 0}}];
F /@ {1, 3, 6, 8}

(* {2,4,6,0} *)
```